# If Linear Programming Decision Variable > 0 then >= 3000

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-statements, solver

I am trying to use the solver in Excel to create a linear program to minimize mutual fund expenses.  My decision variables are the amounts invested in each fund.  If anything is invested, it must meet the fund minimum.  How can I program this?

Amount invested in Fund 1 >= if Amount Invested in Fund 1 > 0, then Amount Invested in Fund 1 >= 3000 else Amount Invested = 0

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

These types of constraints are enforced by a variation of the [Big M Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_M_method)

Suppose that `x` is the decision variable corresponding to the amount to invest in Fund 1. Pick an upper bound `M` on the possible values of `x`. For example, if you only have $1,000,000 to invest, let `M = 1,000,000` You don't need to have the least upper bound on `x`. `M = 2,000,000` would work as well (though you will generally get faster convergence and less round-off error if `M` isn't unreasonably large).

Introduce a new variable, `y`, which is constrained to be `0` or `1` (i.e. a binary decision variable). Add the following two constraints to your model:

```
x >= 3000*y
x <= M*y
```

If `x>0` then the second added constraint forces `y` away from `0`, hence it forces `y = 1` since `y` is binary. But if `y = 1`, this second constraint reduces to `x <= M`, which is automatically true by choice of `M`, thus it doesn't add any genuine constraint on `x`. But -- since `y = 1` in this case, the first constraint becomes `x >= 3000`. Thus the two constraints together force `x >= 3000` as soon as `x > 0`. Importantly -- it does so without use of the nonlinear `if` function. It does make it an MILP (Mixed Integer Linear Programming) problem -- but Excel's solver can handle those with no problem (as long as the number of binary variables doesn't become too large).